# I have 8 brief scripts to restart PCs in diff rooms. One abruptly stopped. No changes have fixed it

Tags: powershell

This script works fine:

```
$machines = get-content H:\0PS\Restart\Inventory417.txt
restart-computer -computername $machines -force
```

This script DID work fine until this week. I made no changes prior to the failure:

```
$machines = get-content H:\0PS\Restart\InventoryAccom.txt
restart-computer -computername $machines -force
```

With the omission of the '417' in the first one and the 'Accom' in the second, there are 100 additional characters in each and they both LOOK identical to me.

Can someone see what I'm missing? The info re: the Powershell version is;

```
Name                         Value
----                         -----
PSVersion                    5.1.14409.1018
PSEdition                    Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions         {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                 10.0.14409.1018
CLRVersion                   4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion            3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion    2.3
SerializationVersion         1.1.0.1
```

Thanks very much!

I've copied working scripts and merely substituted the name of the inventory file and tried running that. The same failure occurred.

### The results for about three years is that the PCs either restarted or reported the PC ID that failed. All of the scripts except for the one indicated above still do so.

None of the scripts have ever returned a list of anything UNLESS there are devices that fail to restart - then those devices are listed.

When I run the script, the following is returned immediately:

PS C:\Windows\system32> $machines = get-content H:\0PS\Restart\InventoryAccom.txt
restart-computer -computername $machines -force
Restart-Computer : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or 
empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:2 char:32
+ restart-computer -computername $machines -force
+                                ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Restart-Computer], ParameterBindingValidationExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Resta 
   rtComputerCommand

### PS C:\Windows\system32>

Sorry. Forgot to mention that I CAN shut them down via shutdown /i.

Comment: Thank you, boxdog.

Comment: What errors (if any) do you get?  what have you tried to resolve the issue?  For example, does the list of machine load ok?  Do they look right?  Can you restart the same machines individually from the same host using the console?

Comment: The error message indicates a null or empty string is being passed to `-ComputerName` in the script. I suggest writing the output of whatever variable is being sent to `-ComputerName` to see when it's happening and then troubleshooting from there.

Comment: Run ((get-content H:\0PS\Restart\InventoryAccom.txt) -notmatch '\S').count and see if you've got a empty line in that file.

Comment: mjolinor - THANKS MUCH! Somehow I'd let two blank lines sneak into the inventory.txt file at the end. Removing them fixed it. Thank you all for your help!